# how to display data from database using java beans

Tags: java, javabeans

I need to display the data requested by the user from the database on my jsp page.How can I do it using java beans?

Comment: This question is quite vague, can you provide more information about the frameworks you're using in your application?

Comment: Basicaaly i need to make an application of a music store using jsp and java beans in which i need to display information about albums according to artist name or artist id.

Answer (score 0):

`java beans` is not a library. It's more like a concept/design pattern for special classes, that hold attributes and provide getter and setter method, which use a naming convention. A quick example:

```
 private String name;
 private String street;

 public getName() {return name};
 public setName() {this.name = name};

 public getStreet() {return street};
 public setStreet() {this.street = street};
```

Now we can design a bean that corresponds to a database table. We just use the columnnames as fieldnames and have a java object that represents a table entry.

Have a look at DAO/DTO patterns and ORM (like JPA or hibernate). Those 'implement' this kind of technique and I'm pretty sure, one of those will help.

Comment: I have used beans to enter uer data into database.
But i am not able to use it to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: Sounds like you're already using some sort of framework and have a specific problem. Show some code and maybe we can provider better help :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to get value of database and give  to bean & then set bean variable into setAttribute() method & retrive to a jsp page.